# Async task and https android

Tags: android, ssl, android-asynctask

I have an android app and added ssl to my website to secure login information when logging in. I have an async task which sends the information to check a database etc.

After setting up my ssl correctley and see that it works on my website. I tried changing http: to https: in the url for my async task and it crashes with this error:

```
08-19 19:14:16.779    9314-9465/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 50: https://myDBUrl
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
        at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ReadLogInJSON.readJSONFeed(ReadLogInJSON.java:90)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ReadLogInJSON.doInBackground(ReadLogInJSON.java:37)
        at com.example.beerportfoliopro.ReadLogInJSON.doInBackground(ReadLogInJSON.java:24)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
```

Update:

FOund out error was not in the ssl part but when using an auto correct keyboard that adds a space at the end of the user name it crashes. How can I eliminate this space if entered?

Comment: after a closer look i think the error was an accidental space in my entered user name double checking now

Comment: You can encode the URL (which would replace the " " by `%20`, I think).

Comment: Normally, you should trim the data before sending and urlencoding as well. This will avoid these issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can always write a util function with you and use it to avoid such errors:

```
private String urlEncode(String url)
    {
        if(url == null)
            return null;
        url = url.replace("[","");
        url = url.replace("]","");
        url = url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: `Uri.encode(String)` would do the same thing. Except that, it will encode all characters other than letters, numbers and unreserved characters.

Comment: @vikram.. The purpose of suggesting this as an Util function, we can control how to encode the url as per our need. You are correct though.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. Look at the exception thrown: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 50: https://myDBUrl at java.net.URI.create`. The issue here does not pertain to _our_ need or preference. We need to comply with `java.net.URI's` specifications. Your util method (after a few more `url.replace(...)` statements) will look similar to `Uri.encode(String)`. So, your suggestion stands correct.